# Merging Branch using Git

Tags: git, tfs, branching-and-merging

We're using TFS2010 for our ASP.Net project's VCS. Recently there's a need to make some minor changes but affecting a lot of files. Since branching is only reserved for major release, we've decided to use a local branch while trying out Git. An isolated team is working on this local branch while the remaining team members are working on bug fixes for the main branch in TFS.

Now we're done and it's time to merge. What we have in mind is to get the latest copy from our TFS and replace into the local branch and manually merge using TortoiseGit.

What would be the recommended process to merge for our case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the latest copy from our TFS and replace into the local branch"?

Comment: @Cupcake I want to merge the latest bug fixes into our local branch. Once tested then we'll checkin the whole thing back into our TFS

Answer (score 1):

> What we have in mind is to get the latest copy from our TFS

That would be a simple `git fetch`

> replace into the local branch and manually merge using TortoiseGit.

Since it is a local branch, not yet push, you can [**rebase it**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

```
git checkout yourLocalBranch
git rebase origin/master
```

That way, you resolve your merges locally, and said branch can be merged back into master at any time (it would be a trivial fast-foward merge).

Comment: Thanks, I did thought about `rebase`, but never use it before. Can you elaborate more on the `rebase` assuming the original TFS branch was `1.0` and bug fixied to `1.0.1` while the local git branch is `1.1`. I'm assuming I need to `rebase` the git branch from `1.0` to `1.0.1` and reapplying `1.1`.